# Play Framework and Java8

Tags: spring, playframework, java-8

I have one Java 8 project and this project is a dependency of Play Web app.
Now whenever I try to instantiate classes rom Java 8 project in Play 2.2.3 web app, it gives me following error:

```
play.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[error: cannot access MongoOperations]
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$14$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(PlayReloader.scala:304) ~[na:na]
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$14$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(PlayReloader.scala:304) ~[na:na]
```

How should let play compile code with Java 8 when I say 'Play "run 8080"'  ? Why play isn't able to access the class in Java 8 project ?

FYI: My JAVA_HOME is pointing to JAVA 8.

Here is how my  build.sbt looks like.
Note that 'content-aggregator' is my local artifact installed in my local maven repo.

```
name := "web"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

resolvers += "Maven central" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "de.undercouch" % "bson4jackson" % "2.1.0" force(),
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.1.0" force(),
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-annotations" % "2.1.0" force(),
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.1.0" force(),
  "org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "2.11.3",
  "com.techr" % "content-aggregator" % "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
  "org.jongo" % "jongo" % "1.0",
  "uk.co.panaxiom" %% "play-jongo" % "0.6.0-jongo1.0"
)     

play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

In 'content-aggregator'(Java 8) project I am using Spring and have injected beans by autowiring.
MongoOperations is autowired in one of the classes and play is yelling about it.
SpringMongoConfig.java is a class from this project which is marked as @configuration annotation.
Now in Play project I have created config class which imports content-aggregator's config class.

```
@Configuration
@Import(SpringMongoConfig.class)
public class SpringConfig  {

}
```

Comment: Can you paste the relevant sections of your `build.sbt`?

Comment: @DonovanMuller Updated question with more info.

Comment: `MongoOperations` seems to be from the [Spring Data MongoDB](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb) project. None of your dependencies seem to pull that project in as a transitive dependency (I can't check your `content-aggregator` project). So either add an explicit dependency for `spring-data-mongodb` or ensure that your `content-aggregator` project is correctly configured to pull in `spring-data-mongodb` as a transitive dependency.

Comment: Well looks like that was the problem. I added dependency in Play project externally  and it is not giving error anymore. However, I was expecting when I put Content-aggregator as a dependency in Play project, that should bring down transitive dependencies as well, clearly that's not happening. What extra I have to tell maven so that it would bring all transitive dependencies in Play project, and I am sure that's the right thing to do instead of adding spring-data-mongo dependency to Play project externally.

Comment: Agreed, that would be the best solution. What scope is `spring-data-mongodb` in the `pom.xml` of your `content-aggregator` project?

Comment: It's default scope i.e. compile, and as far as I know dependencies are propagated to dependent projects as well. Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Yup, should be. What is `content-aggregator`'s `<packaging>`?

Comment: @Donovan Muller It's a JAR

Comment: I whipped up a quick demo. Seems to pull all transitive deps for me. See [here](http://i.imgur.com/74ZOONA.png) for my 'aggregator' projects `pom.xml` and [here](http://i.imgur.com/iCPa1Me.png) when Play/SBT pulls it all in.

Comment: Oh , Thanks for taking efforts to set this up, Looks like I am overlooking something then .. Will check again and let you know. Thanks a bunch!